# Pubnub message and presence handler are invoked multiple times

Tags: reactjs, sockets, event-handling, next.js, pubnub

I`m using Next.js for SSR in my app, also using Pubnub for real-time chat. So I have created my pubnub instance of chat like this in pages/index.js

```
const handleMessage = event => {
 const { message, channel } = event;

 addMessage(channel, message)
};

const handlePresence = event => {
 const { state, channel, action } = event;

 if (action === 'state-change') {
  addPresence({ 
    presence: { lastReadMessageTimestamp: state.lastReadMessageTimestamp }, 
    id: channel,
  })
 }
};

useEffect(() => {
  pubnub.addListener({ 
    message: handleMessage,
    presence: handlePresence, 
  });
  pubnub.subscribe({
    channelGroups: [channelGroup],
    withPresence: true,
  });
}, []);

return (
 <PubNubProvider client={pubnub}>
  <Fragment>
    <section>
      <MetaTags title={MAIN_SEO.title} description={MAIN_SEO.description} />
      <Header />
      <main>
        {children}
      </main>
    </section>
  </Fragment>
 </PubNubProvider>
```

So I have 2 pages, where I should use pubnub, pages/chat.js and pages/messages.js. So while I start from messages page for example all is good, when I go from messages page to chat page, my handler for messages and presence invokes multiple times on next page(and I see for example 3 same messages in a thread), when for real I get only 1 message or only 1 presence. After reloading the page result is at should be(so I see only 1 message which came to me).

Comment: Somehow you are likey intializing the pubnub object and/or listener more than once (a variable scope issue). If you can provide a github repo with install/run repo steps, we can try it over here and provide insights.

Comment: Yeah, also thouth about that. It's a pity, bit can't provide full repo, can provide some more bunches of code,like when I've added `return () => pubnub.unsubscribeAll()` to useEffect, it became ok with message handler, but presence handler still is calling multiple times. Also remember that I`m using next.js, that means that I should subscribe/unsubscribe on every page mount/unmount, and here while I go from any page to another it should do like this.

Comment: I'm not sure about next.js - what about it forces you to subscribe/unsubscribe with every page? Is it static HTML pages you are dealing with that when you nav to next page it loads a new HTML file like back in the old days of webapps?

Comment: If you can enable PN SDK logging (set useVerbosity:true in the pubnub init) then you can reproduce the repeat Presence calls so we can diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed that issues, just added `removeEventListener`:

```
const handleMessage = event => {
  const { message, channel } = event;

  addMessage(channel, message)

};

const handlePresence = event => {
  const { state, channel, action } = event;

  if (action === 'state-change') {
    addPresence({ 
      presence: { lastReadMessageTimestamp: state.lastReadMessageTimestamp }, 
      id: channel,
    })
   }
 };

const pubnubListener = {
  message: handleMessage,
  presence: handlePresence,
}

const leaveApplication = () => {
  pubnub.removeListener(pubnubListener);

  pubnub.unsubscribeAll()
}

useEffect(() => {
  pubnub.addListener(pubnubListener);

  pubnub.subscribe({
    channelGroups: [channelGroup],
    withPresence: true,
  });

  return leaveApplication

}, []);
```